# How to fetch names having multiple values in a single query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have two tables: Person, PersonType

```
    Person                         PersonType                          PersonTypeMapping
personId   name                 typeId     typeName                tId   personId   typeId
  101         p1                  1        Student                 123       101       1
  102         p2                  2        Employee                124       102       1
  103         p3                                                   125       102       2
                                                                   126       103       1
                                                                   127       103       2
```

Now I need to fetch the person names and their corresponding typeNames.

This is my query

```
SELECT Person.personId, Person.name,PersonType.typeName 
from Person 
    INNER JOIN PersonTypeMapping ON PersonTypeMapping.personId = Person.personId 
    INNER JOIN PersonType ON PersonType.typeId = PersonTypeMapping.typeId;
```

My Output:

```
   personId       name        typeName
   101             p1          Student
   102             p2          Student
   102             p2          Employee
   103             p3          Student
   103             p3          Employee
```

But I need output like this:

```
   personId       name        typeName
   101             p1          Student
   102             p2          Student, Employee
   103             p3          Student, Employee
```

What can be done for this?

Comment: ```SELECT Person.personId, Person.name,PersonType.typeName, GROUP_CONCAT(PersonType.typeName SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM Person 
    INNER JOIN PersonTypeMapping ON PersonTypeMapping.personId = Person.personId 
    INNER JOIN PersonType ON PersonType.typeId = PersonTypeMapping.typeId; 
GROUP BY PersonType.typeName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Person.personId, Person.name, Group_Concat(PersonType.typeName) 
from Person 
    INNER JOIN PersonTypeMapping ON PersonTypeMapping.personId = Person.personId 
    INNER JOIN PersonType ON PersonType.typeId = PersonTypeMapping.typeId
GROUP BY Person.personId, Person.name;
```